# How do I convert a .csv file to .tab in R?

Tags: r, file, file-conversion

I need to convert a file of .csv format to one of .tab format. How do I go about this in R?

Comment: You can import the `csv` and write it to file using a tab separator. See `?write.table`.

Comment: `write.table(read.csv('old-file.csv'), 'new-file.tab')`, though there are a lot of other parameters you may want to consider. `readr::write_tsv` and `read_csv` are drop-in replacements with better defaults, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the correct answer from the comments:

```
write.table(read.csv("old-file.csv", sep=","), "new-file.tab")
```

Note that `read.csv` and `write.csv` are just `read.table` and `write.table` with different defaults.

Also as mentioned in the comments, you might find `read_csv` and `write_tsv` from the [readr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=readr) package more pleasant to work with (the built-in R functions can have some surprising behavior).